# What is wrong with my code? RGB potentiometer

Tags: sketch

Arduino programming has been a huge learning curve for me and I am trying to create a project with an rgb that's color is determined by a potentiometer. To where the further I turn it, the further across the rainbow spectrum it goes. I can't figure out how to do all values in between because I am not educated enough but I came up with this basic code...

```
int redpin = 6;
int greenpin = 3;
int bluepin = 5;
int potPin = 0;


void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  pinMode(redpin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(bluepin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(greenpin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(potPin, INPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  int wavecolor = analogRead(potPin);
  Serial.print(wavecolor);
  {
    if (wavecolor = 0) {
      setColor(255, 0, 0);  // red
    }
    if (wavecolor > 0 or wavecolor < 333) {
      setColor(0, 255, 0);  // green
    }
    if (wavecolor > 333 or wavecolor < 667) {
      setColor(0, 0, 255);  // blue
    }
    if (wavecolor > 667 or wavecolor < 1022) {
      setColor(255, 255, 0);  // yellow
    }
    if (wavecolor = 1023) {
      setColor(80, 0, 80);  // purple
    }
  }
}

void setColor(int red, int green, int blue)
{
#ifdef COMMON_ANODE
  red = 255 - red;
  green = 255 - green;
  blue = 255 - blue;
#endif
  analogWrite(redpin, red);
  analogWrite(greenpin, green);
  analogWrite(bluepin, blue);
}
```

And for some reason, where the light should change colors once the potentiometer goes past a certain number, the light just flickers and only changes colors to white when it is all the way up or down. Also, it has a weird flickery yellow color. 
Since I am new to this, can one of you better educated people be willing to assist me?

Comment: think about this .... what will happen if you set the potentiometer to 333?

Answer (score 6):

- Equality comparison in C and C++ is expressed by `==` operator. `==`, not `=`. This

  ```
  if (wavecolor = 0) {
  ```

  actually *assigns* zero to your `wavecolor` variable, thus destroying the value you just read.
- The common sense says that you actually need `and` in your conditions, not `or`

  ```
  if (wavecolor > 0 and wavecolor < 333) {
  ```

  The `or` conditions that you curently use are simply *always true*, which makes them nonsensical.
- This is valid syntax

  ```
  wavecolor > 0 or wavecolor < 333
  wavecolor > 0 and wavecolor < 333
  ```

  but you might want to try using more "canonical" forms

  ```
  wavecolor > 0 || wavecolor < 333
  wavecolor > 0 && wavecolor < 333
  ```

  `or` and `and` are "alternative" forms of `||` and `&&` operators, introduced a long time ago for reasons that are all but obsolete today.
- Assuming that you meant `and` instead of `or`, in your conditions you managed to "exclude" such values as `333`, `667` and `1022` - they wouldn't match any of `and` conditions. Changing some strict comparisons to non-strict ones might be in order.
- As a side note, in a single-file program all file-scope variables should be either `const` or `static`. In your case

  ```
  const int redpin = 6;
  const int greenpin = 3;
  const int bluepin = 5;
  const int potPin = 0;
  ```

Comment: "should be either const or static", saves a few bytes of SRAM too, can come in handy in big programs with lots of variable data.

Comment: Stylistic point: I prefer to write my conditions to look like ranges (in languages that don't have ranges built in), so `0 < wavecolor and wavecolor < 333` rather than `wavecolor > 0 and wavecolor < 333`

Comment: @Alexander: It makes perfect formal sense. But in practice it doesn't always work as well as one might expect. It clashes with another natural principle: express comparisons as "variable vs. limit" in that specific order, since that is how we usually express them in natural language. Which approach will win in the end is a matter of personal preference.

Comment: @AnT Yeah, it's certainly contentious, but I have 3 reasons I prefer it: 1) It "looks" like a range, 2) The operands are ordered from least on the left to greatest on the right (which is usually how things are ordered, e.g. the x axis on a graph)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code below. This will give you the desired output!

```
int redpin = 6;
int greenpin = 3;
int bluepin = 5;
int potPin = 0;


void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  pinMode(redpin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(bluepin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(greenpin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(potPin, INPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  int wavecolor = analogRead(potPin);
  Serial.print(wavecolor);
  {
    if (wavecolor == 0) {
      setColor(255, 0, 0);  // red
    }
    else if (wavecolor > 0 && wavecolor < 333) {
      setColor(0, 255, 0);  // green
    }
    else if (wavecolor >= 333 && wavecolor < 667) {
      setColor(0, 0, 255);  // blue
    }
    else if (wavecolor >= 667 && wavecolor < 1022) {
      setColor(255, 255, 0);  // yellow
    }
    else if (wavecolor >= 1022) {
      setColor(80, 0, 80);  // purple
    }
  }
}

void setColor(int red, int green, int blue)
{
#ifdef COMMON_ANODE
  red = 255 - red;
  green = 255 - green;
  blue = 255 - blue;
#endif
  analogWrite(redpin, red);
  analogWrite(greenpin, green);
  analogWrite(bluepin, blue);
}
```

Read up on logical and relational operators in Arduino (`||`, `&&`, `>`, `<`, `==`, `>=`, `<=`) etc.

 I will leave the logic development to you as it is what develops your coding ability and trust me logic is the most important and fun part of writing a code!